# Magento2 - Checkout shipping method when click Ship here

Tags: magento2, checkout, shipping-methods, shipping-address

http://siteurl/rest/default/V1/carts/mine/shipping-information - **return 404 with below error.**

> "message":"Carrier with such method not found: %1,
>   %2","parameters":["matrixrate","matrixrate_57395"],"trace":"#0
>   [internal function]:
>   Magento\Checkout\Model\ShippingInformationManagement->saveAddressInformation(18678,
>   Object(Magento\Checkout\Model\ShippingInformation))\n#1
>   /public_html/vendor/magento/module-webapi/Controller/Rest.php(307):
>   call_user_func_array(Array, Array)\n#2
>   /public_html/vendor/magento/module-webapi/Controller/Rest.php(216):
>   Magento\Webapi\Controller\Rest->processApiRequest()\n#3
>   /public_html/var/generation/Magento/Webapi/Controller/Rest/Interceptor.php(24):
>   Magento\Webapi\Controller\Rest->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))\n#4
>   /public_html/vendor/magento/framework/App/Http.php(135):
>   Magento\Webapi\Controller\Rest\Interceptor->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))\n#5
>   /public_html/vendor/magento/framework/App/Bootstrap.php(258):
>   Magento\Framework\App\Http->launch()\n#6
>   /public_html/index.php(40):
>   Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap->run(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Http))\n#7
>   {main}"}

Answer (score 0):

You have an issue with Matrixrate. It must be an issue with  Shipping method matrix rate data. Please configure/import Matrixrate rate properly.

Comment: the issue is still coming if i disable matrixrate module.

Comment: Have you got any solutions ?